# Using regex for tab delimited strings with RegexLineTokenizer

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have an input file containing tab delimited strings.  On some lines there maybe multiple consecutive tabs.

I tried using Spring's DelimitedLineTokenizer, but since there are multiple tabs, i had to consider switching to RegexLineTokenizer.

In the RegexLineTokenizer, when i do a setRegex("\t+"), it fails to properly tokenize the lines, and fails with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

I am not sure what am i doing wrong here.

Here's the code:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<RoutingHubInfoId> routingHubIdReader() {
    System.out.println("Reading from file");
    FlatFileItemReader<RoutingHubInfoId> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<RoutingHubInfoId>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("NAM_C4_DATA.txt"));
    DefaultLineMapper<RoutingHubInfoId> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<RoutingHubInfoId>();
    RegexLineTokenizer rlt = new RegexLineTokenizer();
    rlt.setRegex("\t+");
    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(rlt);
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new RoutingHubInfoIdMapper());
    reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);

    return reader;
}
```

The file contains the following lines (a sample)

```
abc def ghi
00089BTT    IOIX    BRA
00089BZA    BzDSA   BRA
```

Now, i tried with another piece of code, and it works.

```
public class RoutingHubIdReader 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException
    {
        File file = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("NAM_C4_DATA.txt").getFile());
        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File exists!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("File doesnt exist!");
        }
        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = lnr.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tokens = line.split("\t+");
            if (tokens.length != 3) {
                System.out.println(("Tokens: size: " + tokens.length + " values: " + Arrays.asList(tokens)));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It seems something simple i am missing, but not sure.  I tried also escaping the `\t+` to `\\t+`, but that didnt work either.

Comment: Can you update the question with code you are using and example you are trying?

Comment: Not clear what are you doing. It would help if you'd provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

> Line-tokenizer using a regular expression to filter out data (by using
>   matching and non-matching groups).

Your regex doesn't define any matching/non matching group so it can't works.
I can't try directly but `rlt.setRegex("([^\t]+)")` should works.